# how to use test fx to test javafx code

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

We are planning to test our java fx scene builder with the help of Test Fx.
For this downloaded the testfx3.1.2 jar,hamcrest-core-1.3.jar,junit.jar,guava-18.0 jar files.

Please look into the below code and please give me some pointers how can i launch my gui.
My controller class which has some additional methods also.

```
public class GuiMainController extends Application implements Initializable{
 @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Plugins");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene((Scene) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
                "/../GuiMain.fxml")));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
    /**
     * to run this class locally.
     * @param args List of Command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And my test class is below.

```
@Category(TestFX.class)
public class GuiMainTest extends GuiTest {
    @Override
    protected Parent getRootNode() {
        Parent parent = null;
        try {
            parent = (Parent)FXMLLoader.load(
               getClass().getResource("/../GuiMain.fxml"));
            return parent;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                   }
        return parent;
    }
    @Test
    public void setBothnamesAndCheckEnabledSearchButton() {
        try{
        ComboBox<String> listPrj = find("#lstProject");//given combobox id.
        listPrj.setValue("ABC");
        if(listPrj.getValue().equals("ABC")) {
            System.out.println("success");
        }   
        }catch(NoNodesFoundException ne){
            System.out.println("node is not available" + ne.getMessage());
        }    }
}
```

It is giving me the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.Scene cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Parent
    at com.trwautomotive.das.rhapsody.plugins.GuiMainTest.getRootNode(GuiMainTest.java:26)
    at org.loadui.testfx.GuiTest$1.run(GuiTest.java:130)
    at org.loadui.testfx.utils.FXTestUtils$4.call(FXTestUtils.java:172)
    at org.loadui.testfx.utils.FXTestUtils$4.call(FXTestUtils.java:168)
    at org.loadui.testfx.utils.FXTestUtils$3.run(FXTestUtils.java:130)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
node is not availableNo nodes matched '#lstProject'.
```

Answer (score 0):

**change**

```
primaryStage.setScene((Scene) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
                "/../GuiMain.fxml")));
```

**to**

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene( FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/../GuiMain.fxml"))));
```

Comment: It is giving the compilation error:  The Constructor Scene(Object) is undefined.

Comment: If I add this: primaryStage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
                "/../GuiMain/GuiMain.fxml")))); there is no compilation error. But GUI is not getting launched. And I have no idea about this.could you please tell me WIll it launch the gui automatically or do I need to do anything to launch the gui? please help me.

Comment: still giving an error ???  Same error or some other ??? can you paste the error massage please...

Comment: Ya same error message it is giving. In general, will it launch the gui automatically?

Comment: if you are getting the same error which is `java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.Scene cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Parent` then you have to check whether you have done  the same mistake somewhere else.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.Scene cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Parent
 at com.trwautomotive.das.rhapsody.plugins.GuiMainTest.getRootNode(GuiMainTest.java:26)at org.loadui.testfx.GuiTest$1.run(GuiTest.java:130)
 at org.loadui.testfx.utils.FXTestUtils$4.call(FXTestUtils.java:172)
 at org.loadui.testfx.utils.FXTestUtils$4.call(FXTestUtils.java:168)
 at org.loadui.testfx.utils.FXTestUtils$3.run(FXTestUtils.java:130)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)

Comment: at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
node is not availableNo nodes matched '#lstProject'.

Comment: Not using the same code anywhere. Only in the controllers start method.

Comment: What do you have in your `GuiTest`??

Comment: The same thing which I have pasted earlier. Nothing more than that. I am very new to this. So I initially just want to test if the value of combobox is "ABC". But I am unable to see the Guui screen. When I launch with launch(args), I am able to see the screen.